# Parse html form into a list of dicts in python / Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I am new to web programming and this is my first SO question, so hopefully I am asking the right way. I am building a simple survey-maker (similar to google forms or survey monkey) and I have a web form that allows the user to add options to a question. Each option has two fields, 'label' and 'value'. The form looks like this:

```
    Option One
           ------------------           ------------------
    Label: |                |   Value:  |                |
           ------------------           ------------------

    Option Two
           ------------------           ------------------
    Label: |                |   Value:  |                |
           ------------------           ------------------
    ...
    ...
    ... // user can "add option" and additional "rows" will appear in the form

[ SUBMIT ]
```

I have used a basic web form like this:

```
<form class="well form" action="/submitform" method="post">
  <p><input type="text" name="label_1">
     <input type="text" name="value_1"></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="label_2">
     <input type="text" name="value_2"></br></p>
  <p>...   // and so forth, to support n sets of two fields
     ...
     ...
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I successfully get request.form and can access each variable in the dict. But of course it's a single flat dict:

```
[{'label_1': 'labelone', 'value1': 'valueone', 'label_2': 'label two'}]
```

and so forth. I want a list of dicts like this:

```
[ {'label': 'labelone', 'value': 'valueone'}, {'label': 'labeltwo', 'value': 'valuetwo'}]
```

I've thought of several hackish ways to do this, but all require foreknowledge of the number and type of form options. I'd rather find a more flexible solution.

Any best practice here? A lot of sites do things like this so I'm guessing there's a best practice that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
l = [{'label_1': 'labelone', 'value_1': 'valueone', 'label_2': 'label two', 'value_2':'v2'}]

values = int(len(l[0])/2)
dicts = []
for i in range(values):
    label_name = 'label_%s' % (i+1)
    value_name = 'value_%s' % (i+1)
    dicts.append({'label':l[0][label_name], 'value':l[0][value_name]})
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps html arrays? (i don't know what they are officially called) combined with [`getlist`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist)

```
<p><input type="text" name="user_label[0]">
     <input type="text" name="user_value[0]"></p>
  <p><input type="text" name="user_label[1]">
     <input type="text" name="user_value[1]"></br></p>
```

I am thinking this could do something like

```
request.form.getlist('user_label')
request.form.getlist('user_value')
```

and you could zip them together to create pairs of `lables: values`

I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS THOUGH, with flask

Comment: I have tested this and it doesn't work. 'Twould be nice if it did.

Answer (score 0):

This is what has worked for me.

In my Jinja tempalates I have the following markup

```
{% for object in objects %}
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{object.id}}">
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{object.name}}">
<input type="text" name="age" value="{{object.age}}">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And then in my Flask app

```
@app.route("/update/", methods=["POST"])
def update_people():
    ids = request.form.getlist('id')
    names = request.form.getlist('name')
    ages = request.form.getlist('age')
    data = [{'id': ids[k], 'name': names[k], 'age': ages[k]} for k,v in enumerate(ids)]
    # [ {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob', 'age': 25 }, ... ]
```